Can i connect every point to every point in gnuplot?
I need to connect all points of Icosahedron together but when i write: splot " " with lines it just connects one point to the next point. I specifically need to connect every single point.
I tried writting some things but nothing have worked out.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show your (non-working) script attempt and provide some minimized realistic test data. Do you really want to connect every point to every point? As far as I understand if you want to draw an icosahedron you only connect the neighboring 3D-convex hull points and maybe fill the resulting polygons, but not connect every point with every other point.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@theozh i really want to connect every point to every point, thats what i need.

Please provide some realistic input data. How does your format look like?

With gnuplot you can define icosahedron as a group of polygons representing the faces of the solid.
To get up to speed with gnuplot polygons, let us start with a cube. To plot a cube you define it's six faces. Each square face is given by a sequence of its vertices with the last vertex being equal to the first to indicate that this is a closed line. Gnuplot paints the face automatically with fillcolour (fc).
# remove axes and other elements to unclutter the plot
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics
# set border style
set style fill solid border lc "black"
# define 6 poligons for the faces
set obj 1 polygon from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 to 1,1,0 to 0,1,0 to 0,0,0 fc "red"
set obj 2 polygon from 0,0,0 to 1,0,0 to 1,0,1 to 0,0,1 to 0,0,0 fc "red"
set obj 3 polygon from 0,0,0 to 0,1,0 to 0,1,1 to 0,0,1 to 0,0,0 fc "red"
set obj 4 polygon from 0,0,1 to 0,1,1 to 1,1,1 to 1,0,1 to 0,0,1 fc "red"
set obj 5 polygon from 0,1,1 to 0,1,0 to 1,1,0 to 1,1,1 to 0,1,1 fc "red"
set obj 6 polygon from 1,0,1 to 1,1,1 to 1,1,0 to 1,0,0 to 1,0,1 fc "red"
# define scale and show
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
set zrange [0:1]
splot NaN

The cube would look like this

Now if you need to plot an icosahedron, you would need to define all  20 triangular faces. You could do it with the following code.
Here we will make the faces semitransparent to avoid glitches when rendering faces that have overlapping projections.
phi = (1 + sqrt(5))/2
unset border
unset key
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset ztics
set style fill transparent solid 0.5 border lc "black"
set obj 1 polygon from 1,0,-phi to -1,0,-phi to 0,phi,-1 to 1,0,-phi fc "blue"
set obj 2 polygon from 0,phi,-1 to phi,1,0 to 1,0,-phi to 0,phi,-1 fc "blue"
set obj 3 polygon from phi,1,0 to phi,-1,0 to 1,0,-phi to phi,1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 4 polygon from -1,0,-phi to 1,0,-phi to 0,-phi,-1 to -1,0,-phi fc "blue" 
set obj 5 polygon from 0,-phi,-1 to phi,-1,0 to 1,0,-phi to 0,-phi,-1 fc "blue"

set obj 6 polygon from 0,phi,1 to 1,0,phi to -1,0,phi to 0,phi,1 fc "blue"
set obj 7 polygon from -1,0,phi to 1,0,phi to 0,-phi,1 to -1,0,phi fc "blue"
set obj 8 polygon from 1,0,phi to phi,-1,0 to 0,-phi,1 to 1,0,phi fc "blue"
set obj 9 polygon from 0,-phi,1 to phi,-1,0 to 0,-phi,-1 to 0,-phi,1 fc "blue"
set obj 10 polygon from phi,1,0 to phi,-1,0 to 1,0,phi to phi,1,0 fc "blue"

set obj 11 polygon from 0,phi,1 to phi,1,0 to 1,0,phi to 0,phi,1 fc "blue"
set obj 12 polygon from 0,phi,-1 to phi,1,0 to 0,phi,1 to 0,phi,-1 fc "blue"
set obj 13 polygon from -phi,1,0 to 0,phi,-1 to 0,phi,1 to -phi,1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 14 polygon from -phi,1,0 to 0,phi,1 to -1,0,phi to -phi,1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 15 polygon from -phi,1,0 to -1,0,phi to -phi,-1,0 to -phi,1,0 fc "blue"

set obj 16 polygon from -phi,1,0 to -phi,-1,0 to -1,0,-phi to -phi,1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 17 polygon from -phi,-1,0 to -1,0,phi to 0,-phi,1 to -phi,-1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 18 polygon from -phi,-1,0 to 0,-phi,1 to 0,-phi,-1 to -phi,-1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 19 polygon from -phi,-1,0 to 0,-phi,-1 to -1,0,-phi to -phi,-1,0 fc "blue"
set obj 20 polygon from -phi,1,0 to 0,phi,-1 to -1,0,-phi to -phi,1,0 fc "blue"

set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set zrange [-2:2]
splot NaN

The resulting shape would look like this:

P.S. Would be nice to define the faces of an icosahedron algorithmically instead of listing them down explicitly.

Although your question contains no data and little efforts (at least you don't show it), here is a starting point.

first, the coordinates of the corners of the icosahedron are calculated and written to a datablock
you plot the data in a nested loop where the starting point is changed and the interval as well. In this way, every corner will be connected with every other corner. Check help every.

Script:
### plot icosahedron with every corner connected an all others
reset session

# create coordinates of corners of icosahedron
set print $Data
    phi = (1+sqrt(5))*0.5
    do for [y=-1:1:2] for [z=-1:1:2] { print sprintf("%9g %9g %9g", 0    , y    , z*phi) }
    do for [x=-1:1:2] for [y=-1:1:2] { print sprintf("%9g %9g %9g", x    , y*phi, 0    ) }
    do for [x=-1:1:2] for [z=-1:1:2] { print sprintf("%9g %9g %9g", x*phi, 0    , z    ) }
set print
print $Data

set view equal xyz
set view 60,72 
set xyplane relative 0 
set key noautotitle
set tics 1
N = 12

splot for [a=0:N-1] for [b=1:N-a-1] $Data every b::a::a+b u 1:2:3 w l lc "blue"
### end of script

Result:
        0        -1  -1.61803
        0        -1   1.61803
        0         1  -1.61803
        0         1   1.61803
       -1  -1.61803         0
       -1   1.61803         0
        1  -1.61803         0
        1   1.61803         0
 -1.61803         0        -1
 -1.61803         0         1
  1.61803         0        -1
  1.61803         0         1


